# How to make the Navigation Drawer Shadow lighter

Tags: java, android

Im pertaining to the one when the drawer is open, the shadow is showing on the right side, this seems dark and the requirement wants to have it a bit lighter.

I've tried changing setDrawerShadow but doesn't seem to change at all.

im using the Gravity.START

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DrawerLayout.setScrimColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setScrimColor%28int%29).