# keep navigation drawer from darkening main screen

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer in my app. When I pull the drawer, it cause the main content to darken a little (a transparency layer with some level of opacity). I want that opacity to go away so that when I open the drawer, the main content's visibility does not change. Now, I don't really want the `push to the right` effect; I just don't want the opacity. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: [You need to adjust the scrim color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517529/how-to-make-the-navigation-drawer-shadow-lighter/21517606#21517606)

Comment: Is there a way of doing this in the xml by any chance? I am using the support lib

Comment: `DrawerLayout` doesn't have any custom attrs, so no.